# How do I create a pie chart in SAS for a variable whose values I've grouped using PROC FORMAT?

Tags: sas, pie-chart

I have a variable `ideology` that takes on values from 1 to 7. I've decided to make these continuous values into three groups using PROC FORMAT like so:

```
proc format;
value ideofmt
   1-2='Lib or Extr Lib'
   3-5='Mod Lib, Slight Lib or Slight Cons'
   6-7='Cons or Extr Cons';
run;
```

I want to create a pie chart that takes into account my grouping of these continuous values, *if possible* without having to modify the data itself.  What I've tried is:

```
proc gchart data=sasuser.project2;
pie ideology /noheading percent=arrow slice=inside value=inside coutline=black 
woutline=2;
format ideology ideofmt.;
run;
```

This gets me a pie chart that has the group labels that I want, but the pie chart is split into 7 slices (corresponding to the 7 values) instead of 3 (corresponding to the 3 groups).

Any help with this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `discrete` option to your pie statement:

```
proc gchart data=sasuser.project2;
pie ideology /noheading percent=arrow slice=inside value=inside coutline=black discrete
woutline=2;
format ideology ideofmt.;
run;
quit;
```

Otherwise, I think SAS assigns slices based on quantiles of your data, ignoring formatted values.

Also, a quit statement is required at the end of proc gchart in addition to the run statement.